# Does T-SQL let you do: SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I'm wondering if T-SQL has something like: SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

Or if there is a way to disable safe update mode in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

We are currently trying to delete duplicate records in our table but it has no primary key. I think this is why we are getting the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "A_LINKED_SERVER" returned message "Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update.".
```

The logical solution would be to add a primary / unique key but we need data to be fed in continuously (we're importing data from one database to another) - by adding a primary / unique key, data would stop coming in once a duplicate record exists and this is not what we want to happen.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Although you mention SSMS in the question, it isn't tagged as a SQL Server question.

Comment: Noted! - thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're trying to delete duplicates but you can't use a key to identify the duplicate records?  How are you expecting to de-duplicate and not completely delete all duplicate records?  And why isn't there a primary key in the sending or source database?

Comment: The plan is to actually delete all the duplicate records.
So there’s two databases (Database A, and Database B) and the duplicate records will only appear in Database A. So currently, for any duplicate records in Database A, I’m choosing a column and placing the value of that column inside a temp table (i.e. placing column: staff_id with the value: 33326971). Then I’m deleting all existence of that record in Database A (even the original). When I do this, I have to update a flag column in Database B; so I use the values I stored in the temp table to target the same records in Database B.

Comment: In regards to why there is no primary key in the first place, I have asked previously and I think that’s just the way it’s been done. We are going migrate to updated software soon and this problem I’m currently looking at is just supposed to be a short term fix as we don’t want to cause too much upset with current proceedings. I understand that a table with no primary key is bad practice and we’re definitely going to ensure that this is not going to be repeated when we migrate and update!

Comment: Add an autogenerated (IDENTITY) column as a PRIMARY KEY.